# Failing to import into JabRef 3.0

Tags: jabref

I am not able to import RIS and also BIB files into my JabRef database or a new database. When I try to import an RIS-file I get the message "Wrong file format". If I try to do so with drag and drop I get "could not find a suitable import format". I know that the files are OK as  I imported these particular files before into JabRef of older version (2.8) and it worked well.
If I try to open a BIB file it opens a file but shows no entries.

What could be the reason for that and how can I solve it? For the moment I am not able to work with JabRef for these reasons.

### Exemplar RIS-file

```
TY  - JOUR
M1  - Copyright (C) 2016 American Chemical Society (ACS). All Rights Reserved.
N1  - CAPLUS AN 2012:446586(Journal; Online Computer File)
PY  - 2012///
PB  - Elsevier B.V.
DO  - 10.1016/j.powtec.2012.01.008
M3  - 10.1016/j.powtec.2012.01.008
AU  - Salustio, P. J.
AU  - Feio, G.
AU  - Figueirinhas, J. L.
AU  - Cabral-Marques, H. M.
AU  - Costa, P. C.
AU  - Pinto, J. F.
T1  - Release profile of ibuprofen in β-cyclodextrin complexes from two different solid dosage forms.
N2  - The objective of this work was to develop solid dosage forms using powders contg. inclusion complexes (ibuprofen with β-cyclodextrin) which were used to produce tablets (direct compression without addnl. excipients) and pellets (extrusion/spheronization) from wet mass contg. 40% (wt./wt.) of microcryst. cellulose.  The pellets also demonstrated that during prepn. of the wet mass, the inclusion process occurred in a same yield that when pre-complexation was used.  The particles characteristics were evaluated after being obtained through different complexation methods.  The results showed that the tensile strength and profile dissoln. were as expected for both dosage forms.  Tablets contg. inclusion complexes showed higher soly. when compared with a ref. formulation and with two com. formulations.  The ibuprofen released from the two pellets formulations didn't show relevant differences between them.  The drug released was analyzed considering different dissoln. parameters.  The advantages of these new methodologies can be summarized as: (a) tablets were produced at a lower cost for the total process; and (b) in the pellet's prepn. there was no need of the previous complexation method resulting in a decrease in time and energy required. [on SciFinder(R)]
JA  - Powder Technol.
JF  - Powder Technology
VL  - 221
SP  - 245
EP  - 251
SN  - 0032-5910
KW  - ibuprofen beta cyclodextrin inclusion complex tablet
ER  -
```

---

BTW I have Windows 7 64bit. Maybe this might be a reason? I would like to avoid upgrading if possible, as I do not have administration rights on my computer and I need to ask an administrator to do that.
How can I provide the said RIS? Here its content:

```
TY  - JOUR
M1  - Copyright (C) 2016 American Chemical Society (ACS). All Rights Reserved.
N1  - CAPLUS AN 2012:446586(Journal; Online Computer File)
PY  - 2012///
PB  - Elsevier B.V.
DO  - 10.1016/j.powtec.2012.01.008
M3  - 10.1016/j.powtec.2012.01.008
AU  - Salustio, P. J.
AU  - Feio, G.
AU  - Figueirinhas, J. L.
AU  - Cabral-Marques, H. M.
AU  - Costa, P. C.
AU  - Pinto, J. F.
T1  - Release profile of ibuprofen in β-cyclodextrin complexes from two different solid dosage forms.
N2  - The objective of this work was to develop solid dosage forms using powders contg. inclusion complexes (ibuprofen with β-cyclodextrin) which were used to produce tablets (direct compression without addnl. excipients) and pellets (extrusion/spheronization) from wet mass contg. 40% (wt./wt.) of microcryst. cellulose.  The pellets also demonstrated that during prepn. of the wet mass, the inclusion process occurred in a same yield that when pre-complexation was used.  The particles characteristics were evaluated after being obtained through different complexation methods.  The results showed that the tensile strength and profile dissoln. were as expected for both dosage forms.  Tablets contg. inclusion complexes showed higher soly. when compared with a ref. formulation and with two com. formulations.  The ibuprofen released from the two pellets formulations didn't show relevant differences between them.  The drug released was analyzed considering different dissoln. parameters.  The advantages of these new methodologies can be summarized as: (a) tablets were produced at a lower cost for the total process; and (b) in the pellet's prepn. there was no need of the previous complexation method resulting in a decrease in time and energy required. [on SciFinder(R)]
JA  - Powder Technol.
JF  - Powder Technology
VL  - 221
SP  - 245
EP  - 251
SN  - 0032-5910
KW  - ibuprofen beta cyclodextrin inclusion complex tablet
ER  - 


TY  - JOUR
M1  - Copyright (C) 2016  U.S. National Library of Medicine.
N1  - MEDLINE AN 2009142766((COMPARATIVE STUDY); Journal; Article; (JOURNAL ARTICLE))
PY  - 2009///
SN  - 1873-3441
AU  - Salustio, P. J.
AU  - Feio, G.
AU  - Figueirinhas, J. L.
AU  - Pinto, J. F.
AU  - Cabral, Marques H. M.
T1  - The influence of the preparation methods on the inclusion of model drugs in a beta-cyclodextrin cavity
N2  - The work aims to prove the complexation of two model drugs (ibuprofen, IB and indomethacin, IN) by beta-cyclodextrin (betaCD), and the effect of water in such a process, and makes a comparison of their complexation yields.  Two methods were considered: kneading of a binary mixture of the drug, betaCD, and inclusion of either IB or IN in aqueous solutions of betaCD.  In the latter method water was removed by air stream, spray-drying and freeze-drying.  To prove the formation of complexes in final products, optical microscopy, UV spectroscopy, IR spectroscopy, DSC, X-ray and NMR were considered.  Each powder was added to an acidic solution (pH=2) to quantify the concentration of the drug inside betaCD cavity.  Other media (pH=5 and 7) were used to prove the existence of drug not complexed in each powder, as the drugs solubility increases with the pH.  It was observed that complexation occurred in all powders, and that the fraction of drug inside the betaCD did not depend neither on the method of complexation nor on the processes of drying considered.[on SciFinder (R)]
JA  - Eur J Pharm Biopharm
JF  - European journal of pharmaceutics and biopharmaceutics : official journal of Arbeitsgemeinschaft fur Pharmazeutische Verfahrenstechnik e.V
VL  - 71
IS  - 2
SP  - 377
EP  - 86
ER  -
```

---

Update 25 Jan 2016
I installed the same version on my Windows 7 (32bit) at home and it was able to import the RIS file.
I also tried the JabRef-3.2.JAR file on the computer that is having the problem above (Wndows 7, 64bit) and the also this version was not able to import the RIS file.
Is this possibly a bug?

---

Update 27 Jan 2016
I tried with JabRef-2.11.1.Jar. It was able to import the RIS file, only when Language is set on English and encoding set on ASCII. Using other endconding leads to the same error.This trick, however, did not resolve the issue with JabRef-3.2.JAR nor with the installed 3.0

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) Please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077) of such a RIS file.

Comment: I installed JabRef on Windows and Linux on which it works fine with the JabRef's current version (2.10). At least for the example on [this Nature homepage](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v5/n10/full/nphys1373.html).

Comment: With Windows 7 and JabRef 3.2 it works too. Maybe you want to upgrade

Comment: Could you post to the [issue tracker of JabRef](https://github.com/jabref/jabref/issues)? Maybe issue [296](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref/issues/296) is related.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me using JabRef 3.2 (I have not tested with earlier versions).

I saved your example in a file name test.RIS , then:

- "File -> Import into new database".

  > A windows entitled "open" pops up.
- Selection of the file: test.RIS
- Selection of the filter: RIS
- Click on OK

  > Done